# Finding radius of graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

The radius of a graph G is defined by the minimum eccentricity of the nodes in the graph. What kind of algorithm do I need in order to solve this?

Using the Floyd-Warshall algorithm to find the diameter of a graph, I'm wondering if the n*n array of distances that I used in the said algorithm can also be used to find the radius.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it could. For each vertex, find its eccentricity by finding the maximal distance from it to any other node, and choose the minimal out of these, to get the radius.

Pseudo Code:

```
radius = infinity
for each vertex v:
    eccentricity = -infinity
    for each vertex u:
         eccentricity = max(eccentricity ,d(v,u))
    radius = min(radius, eccentricity )
```

In the above, `d(v,u)` is the distance between `v` to `u`, that you have as a result of Floyd-Warshall.

Comment: I suppose the complexity of this algorithm is `O(n^2)` where `n` is the number of nodes in the graph. Is there any more optimal algorithm that can scale to graphs of size billions of nodes/edges?